# how to print first 10 lines of a text file using Unix system calls?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I want to write my own version of the `head` Unix command, but my program is not working.

I am trying to to print the first 10 lines of a text file, but instead the program prints all the lines. I specify the file name and number of lines to print via command-line arguments. I am only required to use Unix system calls such as `read()`, `open()` and `close()`.

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFFERSZ 256
#define LINES 10

void fileError( char*, char* );

int main( int ac, char* args[] )
{
    char buffer[BUFFERSZ];
    int linesToRead = LINES;
    int in_fd, rd_chars;

    // check for invalid argument count
    if ( ac < 2 || ac > 3 )
    {
        printf( "usage:  head FILE [n]\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    // check for n
    if ( ac == 3 )
        linesToRead = atoi( args[2] );

    // attempt to open the file
    if ( ( in_fd = open( args[1], O_RDONLY ) ) == -1 )
         fileError( "Cannot open ", args[1] );

    int lineCount = 0;

    //count no. of lines inside file
    while (read( in_fd, buffer, 1 ) == 1) 
    {        
        if ( *buffer == '\n' )
        {
           lineCount++;
        }
    }
    lineCount = lineCount+1;

    printf("Linecount: %i\n", lineCount);

    int Starting = 0, xline = 0;

    // xline = totallines - requiredlines
    xline = lineCount - linesToRead;
    printf("xline: %i \n\n",xline);

    if ( xline < 0 )
        xline = 0;

    // count for no. of line to print
    int printStop = lineCount - xline;
    printf("printstop: %i \n\n",printStop);

    if ( ( in_fd = open( args[1], O_RDONLY ) ) == -1 )
        fileError( "Cannot open ", args[1] );

    //read and print till required number
    while (Starting != printStop) {
        read( in_fd, buffer, BUFFERSZ );
        Starting++;    //increment starting
    }

    //read( in_fd, buffer, BUFFERSZ );
    printf("%s \n", buffer);

    if ( close( in_fd ) == -1 )
        fileError( "Error closing files", "" );
    return 0;
}

void fileError( char* s1, char* s2 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Error: %s ", s1 );
    perror( s2 );
    exit( 1 );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Minor: Why use `ac, args` instead of the very common `argc, argv` in `int main( int ac, char* args[] )`?

Comment: Have a look at the source:  https://github.com/goj/coreutils/blob/rm-d/src/head.c

Comment: In fileError, the call to `perror` is erroneous. fprintf may have modified errno, an you will get an unexpected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very odd that you open the file and scan it to count the total number lines before going on to echoing the first lines.  There is absolutely no need to know in advance how many lines there are altogether before you start echoing lines, and it does nothing useful for you.  If you're going to do it, anyway, however, then you ought to `close()` the file before you re-open it.  For your simple program, this is a matter of good form, not of correct function -- the misbehavior you observe is unrelated to that.

There are several problems in the key portion of your program:

> ```
>     //read and print till required number
>     while (Starting != printStop) {
>         read( in_fd, buffer, BUFFERSZ );
>         Starting++;    //increment starting
>     }
>
>     //read( in_fd, buffer, BUFFERSZ );
>     printf("%s \n", buffer);
> ```

1. You do not check the return value of your `read()` call in this section.  You must check it, because it tells you not only whether there was an error / end-of-file, but also how many bytes were actually read.  You are not guaranteed to fill the buffer on *any* call, and only in this way can you know which elements of the buffer afterward contain valid data.  (Pre-counting lines does nothing for you in this regard.)
2. You are performing raw `read()`s, and apparently assuming that each one will read exactly one line.  That assumption is invalid.  `read()` does not give any special treatment to line terminators, so you are likely to have reads that span multiple lines, and reads that read only partial lines (and maybe both in the same read).  You therefore cannot count lines by counting `read()` calls.  Instead, you must scan the valid characters in the read buffer and count the newlines among them.
3. You do not actually print anything inside your read loop.  Instead, you wait until you've done all your reading, then print everything the buffer after the last read.  That's not going to serve your purpose when you don't get all the lines you need in the first read, because each subsequent successful read will clobber the data from the preceding one.
4. You pass the buffer to `printf()` as if it were a null-terminated string, but you do nothing to ensure that it is, in fact, terminated.  `read()` does not do that for you.

I have trouble believing your claim that your program always prints all the line of the designated file, but I can believe that it prints all the lines of the specific file you're testing it on.  It might do that if the file is short enough that the whole thing fits into your buffer.  Your program then might read the whole thing into the buffer on the first `read()` call (though it is not guaranteed to do so), and then read nothing on each subsequent call, returning -1 and leaving the buffer unchanged.  When you finally print the buffer, it still contains the whole contents of the file.

Comment: Rewinding the file is an option too (instead of reopening it) — `lseek(fd, 0L, SEEK_SET)` would do the trick, IIRC.

Comment: @John Bollinger by now you must have realized that I am new in programming C. I appreciate your input but still I am not sure on what to fix and change my code so my program runs correctly by printing first 10 lines. I would appreciate if you could help me make changes to my code.

Comment: @bmalhi, I *have* helped you.  Working out the details for yourself will be good for you.

Comment: @JohnBollinger can you please explain what do you mean by "scan the valid characters in the read buffer and count the newlines among them." I did scanned the buffer through read and then how do I exactly count the newlines? Sorry for asking too many question but I have a deadline for this assignment tomorrow and need to do it before that. I very confused with C syntax as I am new to C and it is complex for me to understand it. Thanks

Comment: @bmalhi, the return value of the most recent `read()` tells you the size of the portion of the buffer that contains valid characters.  Among those valid characters, you will find a newline (`'\n'`) at the end of the characters for each line, with the possibly exception of the last line in the file.  "[Scanning] the valid characters in the buffer" means writing an inner loop that examines each of the valid characters.